# word2vec implementation in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec

I want to implement word2vec using tensorflow 2.0
I have prepared dataset according to the skip-gramm model and I have got approx. 18 million observations(target and context words).

I have used the followng dataset for my goal:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs/notebooks

I have created a new dataset for n-gramm model. I have used windows_size 2 and number of skips equal to 2 as well in order to create for each target word(as our input) create context word(that is what I have to predict). It looks like this:

```
target  context
  1        3
  1        1
  2        1 
  2       1222
```

Here is my code:

```
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((target, context))
dataset_train = dataset_train.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

#Parameters:
num_words = len(word_index)#approximately 100000
embed_size = 300
num_sampled = 64
initializer_softmax = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()
#Variables:
embeddings_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([num_words,embed_size],-1.0,1.0))
softmax_weight = tf.Variable(initializer_softmax([num_words,embed_size]))
softmax_bias = tf.Variable(initializer_softmax([num_words]))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()


#As before, we are supplying a list of integers (that correspond to our validation vocabulary words) to the embedding_lookup() function, which looks up these rows in the normalized_embeddings tensor, and returns the subset of validation normalized embeddings.  
#Now that we have the normalized validation tensor, valid_embeddings, we can multiply this by the full normalized vocabulary (normalized_embedding) to finalize our similarity calculation:
@tf.function
def training(X,y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_weight,X)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights = softmax_weight, biases = softmax_bias, inputs = embed,
                                   labels = y, num_sampled = num_sampled, num_classes = num_words))
    variables = [embeddings_weight,softmax_weight,softmax_bias]  
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss,variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients,variables))


EPOCHS = 30
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print('Epoch:',epoch)
    for X,y in dataset_train:
        training(X,y)  


#compute similarity of words: 
norm =  tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings_weight), 1, keepdims=True))
norm_embed = embeddings_weight/ norm
temp_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(norm_embed,X)
similarity = tf.matmul(temp_emb,tf.transpose(norm_embed))
```

But the computation of even 1 epoch lasts too long. Is it possible somehow to improve the perfomance of my code?(I am using google colab for the code execution)

**EDIT:** this is a shape of my train dataset

```
dataset_train

<BatchDataset shapes: ((None,), (None, 1)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>
```

I was following the instructions from this guide: https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-tutorial-tensorflow/

Answer (score 0):

This is because softmax function is computationally quite expensive while dealing with possibilities of millions of points in Word2Vec algorithm as explained [here](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/). A faster training would be possible with negative sampling.